# How can I create dynamic table with 3 rows and unlimited columns in php, html, script? I also need a button in each field which links to a site

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, wordpress

This is what i have so far, It outputs a single column table with the links. I want it so that I have a linked button instead of text and I want 3 rows and infinite columns with all the data from the database.

for example,
row->name= [a, b, c, d, e, f]
row->link= [www.google.com, link, link, link, link, link]

```
<?php
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name, link FROM `dbtable`");
    if(!empty($results))
    {    
      echo "<table class ='table'>";
      echo "<tbody>";      
      foreach($results as $row){   
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='$row->link'>$row->name</a>";
        "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";}
      echo "</tbody>";
      echo "</table>";}
?>
```

Comment: Unlimited columns?   That’s...  different. Why 3 rows?  Are you wanting them evenly divided?

Comment: I did the same thing I made the PHP server generate a table on my HTML website. The method I use is similar to what  my answer is.

Comment: @TimMorton Yes, I want it to be evenly divided, Unlimited as in for every name in the database. EthanZone- I already have that on the code i provided. I am having trouble figuring out how i can create a 3 row and as needed columns for the data i have. Also, Buttons instead of text would be more ideal.

Comment: Find the size of the array, divide by three. Have an outer loop that iterates three times, inner loop that iterates size times.  Display result[outer*inner].  Or, if you want to list first three in col 1, next 3 in col 2, etc, you could use modulo (%)...  But in all honesty horizontal scrolling is rather unorthodox because it’s quite impractical for the user. It would be much better to use something like bootstrap or foundation and let css do the work for you (and the content would not scroll horizontally).

Comment: Important concept regardless of which way you do it: separate logic and presentation. Get your data, work with it, and then show the html.

Answer (score 1):

This will make one row with all the links.

```
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name, link FROM `dbtable`"); 
?>
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
if(!empty($results)) {
   foreach($results as $row){
       ?>
            <td>
            <a href='<?php echo $row->link; ?>'><?php echo $row->name; ?></a>
            </td>
        <?php
   }
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You can probably figure out the rest. I am sorry if this had bad format, I wrote it on my phone!